# Blazor WASM app API call being aborted on 400 error

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Some code is omitted for brevity. It's .NET Core 5 Blazor WASM.

I have a component with this in the code block:

```
private List<ToDoDetailDto> listOfTodos = new List<ToDoDetailDto>();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    listOfTodos = await TodoService.GetTodos();
}
```

That component calls the UI ToDo service:

```
public class TodoService: IToDoService
{
  private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

  public TodoService(HttpClient httpClient)
  {
    if (httpClient == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Http is null.");
    this.httpClient = httpClient;
  }

  public async Task<List<ToDoDetailDto>> GetTodos()
  {
    var todos = await this.httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<ToDoDetailDto>> 
                 ($"api/todos/GetAllTodos");
    return todos;
  }
}
```

In my Server folder: I have this:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/todos")]
[ApiController]
public class ToDosController: ControllerBase
{

  [HttpGet(Name = "GetAllTodos")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllTodos()
  {
     List<ToDoDetailDto> todoList = await todoRepo.GetAllTodosAsync();
     return Ok(todoList );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong property of HttpMethodAttribute. Try changing the attribute of the controller method to

```
[HttpGet("GetAllTodos")]
```

Also (not related to the problem), but REST API routes should not contain verbs, it is redundant with the http verb. You can read more about REST API conventions [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forget authorize.
in your controller having authorize

```
[Authorize]
```

If you has logged in. So you should try to check your result from debug.